# Submit button outside Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

On my page I have toolbar which comes from Masterpage, and some input fields.
All input fields are inside of tag **form** and toolbar outside tag **form**.
Is it possible submit form after pressing on button outside of **form tag**?

Please suggest,
Alexander.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it with JavaScript:

```
<input type="button" onclick="$('#someForm').submit();" />
```

The disadvantage, of course, is that it breaks without JavaScript.

I don't believe you can do what you ask without JavaScript, though.

Comment: Isn't there a nested double quote problem in the above?

Answer (score 5):

Use the OnClick-event of the button to submit the form, f.e.:

```
<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON OnClick="document.formname.submit();" VALUE="Submit">
```

Comment: Getting this error "No parameterless constructor defined for this object."

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but what I recently did to solve this problem is the following:

I didn't submit the form per se because of other issues but I called a sub in the VB code and just referenced the text box.

```
<asp:Button ID="SubmitButton"
         runat="server"
         class="TextButton"
       onclick="SubmitButton_Click"
          Text="Submit" />
```

then from there called a nice little sub in the behind file

```
Partial Public Class SurveyQuestions
Protected Sub SubmitButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
```

and then just a simple

```
Request("nameofcontrolhere")
```

and hey! Presto! It works without the use of a form, thereby allowing your button to be wherever you'd like.

Comment: The question was about asp.net MVC, not classic ASP.NET