# Calling Post method using HTML.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have read multiple posts on similar issue but did not work.

I have fixed footer buttons and facing issue in calling "Post" version **Edit** action in **Project** controller. Here is what I'm trying to do

[image: Error]

Let me know if question needs further explaination.

(I tried using Ajax.ActionLink which is suggested in multiple posts too but did not work out.

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048778/asp-net-mvc-actionlink-and-post-method)

Answer (score 7):

Finally I managed to fix it by some workarounds. Posting solution here to help someone.

Like I said earlier, I tried using Ajax.ActionLink but I was not able to achieve the same. Instead I looked for **Calling Form Submit action from outside of form** that's what I actually need here.

**Form:** Name your Form something, say "editProjDetailsForm"
 `@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post,

                        new { @class = "form-horizontal",

    name = "editProjDetailsForm" }))`

**Footer:** Call this method from the footer button.

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.editProjDetailsForm.submit();" 
       class="btn btn-primary"
       value="Save Changes" />
```

I tried this one too in footer but it did not workout:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Save Changes", "Edit", new { id = Model.ProjectId }, 
              new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })
```

**Helpful Posts**

1. [Naming A form using Begin Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683366/naming-a-form-html-beginform)
2. [Submit Button outside HTML.BeginForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974905/submit-button-outside-html-beginform)
3. [Submit Button outside HTML.BeginForm (another link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag)
4. [ASP.net ActionLink and POST Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048778/asp-net-mvc-actionlink-and-post-method)
5. [Error in case you have parameterized constructor in ViewModel and
   did not declare parameterless constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355464/asp-net-mvc-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-object)

**Display Issue if you are using bootstrap** In footer I had one input type = button and one action link with class= button. Both nested in one btn-group but there height were appearing different as visible in following snapshot:

[image: Different buttons]

**Fix:** Found that it is a known issue and there is one suggested solution but did not work out much for me (i.e. for Internet Explorer).
[input type=submit and anchor button in btn-group appear as different sizes](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4982)

Solution: add `.btn { line-height:normal!important; }` or if you want to do only for a specific button lets say the above input button then do this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.editProjDetailsForm.submit();" 
     class="btn btn-primary"
     value="Save Changes" 
     style="line-height:normal!important;" />
```

Comment: Although not entirely relevant to an issue I had, I did gleem some helpful information from this post, so thanks!